# Can I use AA Duracell non-rechargeable in parallel?

Tags: arduino, batteries

I have never used non-rechargeable AA Duracell in parallel. I now have an application where I am forced to use batteries.

To increase battery capacity I am thinking of connecting AA Duracell in parallel for Arduino MCU Project.

I have seen rechargeable cells in parallel, but not conventional.

- What happens if I connect non-rechargeable batteries in parallel?
- Will those batteries charge each other?
- Will they explode?

Comment: what kind of a Non Rechargeable AA Duracell?  (what chemistry are you talking about?) ......... edit the question ....  do not  put info into comments

Comment: I have an Arduino MCU running on 2 AA batteries **in series**. It flashes an LED and sends an 433 MHz RF signal every couple of seconds. It runs for **at least a year** on a fresh set of Alkaline AA cells. What consumes so much energy in your application? It cannot be only the Arduino, if it does you might be using it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

AA batteries in parallel are perfectly fine, and necessary for increased current and capacity. Source: [Energizer themselves](http://data.energizer.com/design_hints/pages/dhints_seriesparallel.html)

The common assertion that this is unsafe or not recommended is only true when batteries in different states of discharge are connected, and in this case, high currents can flow and batteries can heat. Solution: "If there is a high likelihood of a device user installing dissimilarly discharged cells, we recommend incorporating blocking diodes into the device circuit to limit charging between parallel strings.  Blocking diodes can be used to limit charging between parallel battery strings that are not similarly discharged but the voltage drop caused by the diode can be undesirable in circuit design. Schottky diodes are well suited for blocking current between parallel strings due to their low voltage drop."

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to use batteries like these in parallel. The battery that has the higher voltage will be delivering current to the load and then be also trying to charge the battery with the lower voltage. Even small amounts of charging attempted to non-rechargeable cells can can lead to overheating and cell degradation.

If you need higher capacity switch over to using C or D cells. These should be easily available at the same place you find your AA cells.

Comment: What about resistors in-line for each one?